# standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory when using distroless to build rust app

Tags: docker, rust, distroless

When I am using [static-debian11](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) as the base image to run the rust app, shows error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

this is the `main.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    print!("hello world");
}
```

and this is the dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM rust:1.54-bullseye as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN cargo build --release
# RUN cargo build
# do not use slim image, will block when query database
FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian11
LABEL maintainer="jiang@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
# ENV ROCKET_PORT=11014
COPY --from=builder /app/.env /app
COPY --from=builder /app/settings.toml /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/alt-server /app/
CMD ["/app/alt-server"]
```

this is the cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "alt-server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
```

I have already using the [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to check the docker image and make sure the `/app/alt-server` are exists. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the executable _completely_ statically-linked? Any attempt to use the dynamic linker at all and you'd expect this error, because `ld.so` is the "interpreter" used to run dynamic executables, much as something like python or bash is used as an interpreter to run a script; interpreter can't be found -> executable gives a "no such file or directory" during attempt.

Comment: ...see [How to generate statically linked executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770604/how-to-generate-statically-linked-executables) specifying the need to use `target-feature=+crt-static`. Also, [How to build a rust app free of shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766239/how-to-build-a-rust-app-free-of-shared-libraries)

Comment: (If you want to confirm whether the above comments accurately reflect your problem, use `ldd` to inspect the `alt-server` executable)